# Hangman stats error

Tags: java

My code does not show the number of wins, losses and numberOfGames I had played.

I've been trying to fix it for the last month and I'm going nowhere!

```
    import java.util.Random;
     import java.util.Scanner;

   public class HangmanP2 {


public static void main(String[] args) {

  Scanner Input = new Scanner(System.in);
       String first, reverse = "";
        String second, reverse2 = "";
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

   System.out.println("Welcome to Hangman!");
   System.out.println("Enter your first name.");
   first = in.nextLine();
   System.out.println("Enter your last name to play.");
   second = in.nextLine();

  int length = first.length();
  int length2 = second.length();
  for ( int i = length - 1 ; i >= 0 ; i-- )
     reverse = reverse + first.charAt(i);
     reverse = reverse.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + reverse.substring(1).toLowerCase();
 for ( int i = length2 - 1 ; i >= 0 ; i-- )
     reverse2 = reverse2 + second.charAt(i);
     reverse2 = reverse2.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + reverse2.substring(1).toLowerCase();

  System.out.println("Your name entered in reverse is: "+reverse+" "+reverse2);

   startGame(reverse,reverse2);
    }
    public static void startGame(String reverse,String reverse2){


            Random rnd = new Random ();
    Scanner user = new Scanner (System.in);
            String guess = "";
    String message = "";
    int count = 1;
    boolean quit = false;
    String fullWord = "";
    int wins=0;
            int loss=0;
            int numberOfGames=0;
    int guessC = 5;
    String usedLetters ="";
    String remainingLetters ="";
    String letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    int hinter = 0;
    int z  = rnd.nextInt(10);
    int k  = rnd.nextInt(2);

    String words[][] = {{"earth","stars","light",
    "world","about","again",
    "stars","light","music",
    "happy","water","amber",
    "apple","piano","green",
    "mouth","suger","stone",
    "japan","china","after","lemon",
    "grand",
    "lives","twice","print"},{"smile",
    "puppy","latin","vegan","phone","april",
    "south","house","hangs","woman",
    "power","today","india","night","candy",
    "forum","birth","other","chris","irish",
    "paste","queen","grace","crazy","plant",
    "knife","spike","darth","vader","eagle",
    "egypt","range","fists","fight","glory",
    "March","smart","magic","codes","rolls",
    "match","honor","glass","board","teams",
    "bully","zebra","under","mango","brain",
    "dirty","eight","zeros","train","cycle",
    "break","necks","terms","slide","large"},{"stake","guess","wrong","anime","stick","outer","input"},{ "thing","write","white","black"}};




    //Prints info of the game and topic that as been selected
    System.out.println("Welcome to Hangman"+" "+reverse+" "+reverse2);


    //This prints the '-' and spaces for the first run of the game only
    for(int index = 0; index < words[z][k].length();index++)
    {
        Character variableInt = words[z][k].charAt(index);
        if(variableInt != ' ')
        {
            message += "-";
        }
        else
        {
            message += " ";
        }
    }
    //Nothing will change, this prints information to the user about his current status in-game.
    System.out.println("Secret word: \t\t" +  message);
    System.out.println("Letters Remaining: " + letters);
    System.out.println("Letters Used: ");
    System.out.println("Guesses Remaining: " + guessC);
    //The loop that will continuously run the game, until the user fails or does not want to play again.
    do{
        //The following variable's make sure there is not stacking from previous data when the loop runs again.
        remainingLetters = "";
        count = 0;
            //Ask the user for a letter to guess

        System.out.println("\nEnter a letter to guess the word): ");
        guess = user.nextLine();
        //The following for-loop converts ASCII table [A-Z] to actually characters and if the player used a letter it will not show up or add to the string each run of the do-loop.
        for(int x = 65; x < 91;x++){
            Character current = new Character ((char)x);
            String current2 =  current.toString();
            if(!usedLetters.contains(current2)){
                remainingLetters += current;
            }       
        }
        //Converts the user's first character to a string which is converted into another character and again converted into a String (Seem's useless) but i used it this way cause i was getting an error.
        Character convert = new Character (guess.charAt(0));
        Character conv =  new Character (convert);
        String converted = convert.toString();
        //The letters the player uses will be added to a string, if it has not already been added and only if it is a letter.
        if(!usedLetters.contains(converted) && conv.isLetter(convert)){
        usedLetters+=guess.charAt(0);
        }
        //Inside this for-loop it turns our word into a String and the user's first character into a string.

        for(int index = 0; index < words[z][k].length();index++){
    //This is a helper 
            count++;
            //Conversion of variables
            Character current2 = new Character ( words[z][k].charAt(index));
            String current = current2.toString();
            Character current3 = new Character (guess.charAt(0));
            String current4 = current3.toString();
            String current5 = current4.toUpperCase();
            String current6 = words[z][k].toUpperCase();
            //If the players gets a letter correct, do the following.
            if(current4.equalsIgnoreCase(current))
            {
                //Add's on to the previous string from where the player got it correct and change it to the correct letter instead of a '-'.
                message = message.substring(0,index) + guess + message.substring(index + 1);
            }
            //If the player gets it wrong and the helper variable is equal to 1 (so that it does not follow the loop of the for-loop and it is not one of the special characters in the game('!' or '?').
            if(!current6.contains(current5) && count == 1 && guess.charAt(0) != '?' && guess.charAt(0) != '!'){
                guessC--;
            }
        }
//Prints information to the user of their current topic



        //The secret word the player has to guess
        System.out.println("Secret word: \t\t" + message.toUpperCase());
            //The letters in the alphabet that have not been used yet
        System.out.print("\nLetters remaining: ");
        System.out.print(remainingLetters.toUpperCase() + "\n\n");
        //This will print a message to the user, telling them information on using a hint or the hint itself.

        //Letters the user has used since the game session has been running
        System.out.print("\nLetters Used: ");
        System.out.print(usedLetters.toUpperCase() + "\n");
        //The amount of guesses the player has left
        System.out.println("\nGuesses Remaining: " +guessC );
        //If the player enters a '?' it will do the following.
        if(guess.charAt(0) == '?'){
            if(hinter <2){
                //Displays what is in the array and information about the delay, while losing guesses.
            hinter++;
            System.out.print("\nHint will appear after next guess! \n");
            guessC -=2;
            }
        }
        //If the user guesses the word correct
        if(message.equalsIgnoreCase(words[z][k])){
            System.out.println("YOU ARE CORRECT! " +  words[z][k] + " is correct!");
            wins++;
                            quit = true;
        }
        //If the user ask to guess the entire word it is stored in a separate variable and make quit equal to true.
        if(guess.charAt(0) == '!')
        { 
            System.out.print("\nEnter the secret word: ");
            fullWord = user.nextLine();
            //if the user guesses the word correct then it will tell the user they are correct and make quit equal to true.
            if(fullWord.equalsIgnoreCase(words[z][k])){
                System.out.println("YOU ARE CORRECT! " +  words[z][k] + " is correct!");
                wins++;
                                    quit = true;

            }
            //If the user does not get it right it will tell the user they are wrong and make quit equal to true.
            else{
                System.out.println("YOU ARE INCORRECT! the word is: " +  words[z][k] + " ");
                loss++;
                                    quit = true;
            }
        }
        //If the guesses counter equal 0 then it will tell them that they have lost and make quit equal to true.
        if(guessC == 0){
            System.out.println("GAME OVER! The secret word was [ " + words[z][k] + " ]!");
            loss++;
                            quit = true;
        }
        //This is what happens when quit eventually becomes true, the user is asked if they would like to play again.
        if(quit == true){
            System.out.println("\nWould you like to play again (Y or quit)? ");
                            System.out.println("\nOr type [stats] to check your work");
            guess = user.nextLine();
        //If they do want to play again, they will need to enter Y and if they do it will give them another word to guess and resets there information so that there will be no overlap.    
        if(guess.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")){
            quit = false;

                            z  = rnd.nextInt(10);
             k  = rnd.nextInt(2);
             guess = " ";
            guessC = 6;
             message = "";
             usedLetters = "";
             hinter = 0;



                for(int index = 0; index < words[z][k].length();index++)
                {
                    Character variableInt = words[z][k].charAt(index);
                    if(variableInt != ' ')
                    {
                        message += "-";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        message += " ";
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("Secret word: \t\t" +  message);
                System.out.println("Letters Remaining: " + letters);

                System.out.println("Letters Used: ");
                System.out.println("Guesses Remaining: " + guessC);

                    }

        if(guess.equals("stats")){  
         printGameStats(wins,loss,numberOfGames);


                    }
                    else{
            //If the user enters 'N' then they will be told the following and the scanner will be closed.
            System.out.println("THANK YOU FOR PLAYING HAVE A GOOD DAY!");
            user.close();
        }
        }
    //end of the while loop which will only stop if quit equals true.
    }while(quit != true );

            }           

private static void printGameStats(int wins,int loss,int numberOfGames) {





    // Line
    System.out.print("+");
    printDashes(37);
    System.out.println("+");

    // Print titles
    System.out.printf("|  %6s  |  %6s  |  %12s  |\n",
            "WINS", "LOSSES", "GAMES PLAYED");

    // Line
    System.out.print("|");
    printDashes(10);
    System.out.print("+");
    printDashes(10);
    System.out.print("+");
    printDashes(10);
    System.out.print("+");
    printDashes(16);
    System.out.print("+");
    printDashes(18);
    System.out.println("|");

    // Print values
    System.out.printf("|  %6d  |  %6d  | %12d  |\n",
            wins, loss, numberOfGames);

    // Line
    System.out.print("+");
    printDashes(37);
    System.out.println("+");
}


private static void printDashes(int numberOfDashes) {
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfDashes; i++) {
        System.out.print("-");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: time to learn to use a debugger.

Comment: Even more important: time to learn how to write clean code. Human readable that is. You should not push so much content into that poor method. It does not come as surprise that you need other people to find the bug(s) in this mess.